# tracking points on a 3D image sequence export for use in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d, tracking

This is the most complex question I have ever tried to post.. so please excuse me if anything is unclear and dont hesitate to ask questions...

I have a 3d model of a car that i need to export a image sequence of for rotation on a website.. but on the right wheel there always needs to be a certain div while rotating... a good example would be [**this**](http://zachberry.com/examples/threejs/3d-to-2d/). unfortuantly this does need to work in IE8 so i cant use it...

Is this possible? i mean if you can export 3d tracking points from programs such as [**boujou**](http://www.vicon.com/boujou/), would it not be possible to use that information in JavaScript to position the x and y and cheat the depth with scale?

Any suggestions/help/advice more then welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you will need an array of x and y coordinates that define the trajectory of your div. Create a function that positions your div on top of your main car image, that takes x and y coordinates as parameters. Then call that function from your main loop that rotates the car, giving it the current x and y from the array.

Alternatively, you could write a function that will calculate the x and y positions. I found these URLs helpful when doing something similar:

http://13thparallel.com/archive/maths-and-dhtml/example3.htm
http://tadhg.com/wp/2007/02/19/animating-circles-with-javascript/